# Erro: The type or namespace name 'Logic' does not exist in the namespace 'Game.Logic.AI.Game'

Tags: c#

> Erro  12  The type or namespace name 'Logic' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Game.Logic.AI.Game' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

Como posso resolver? Já tenho um projeto chamado `Game.Logic` e meu código está assim:

```
  namespace Game.Logic.AI.Game
{
    using Game.Logic.AI;

    public class GControl0 : APVEGameControl
    {
        public static readonly GControl0 Simple = new GControl0();
    }
}
```

Comment: o using Game.Logic.AI; vem antes do namespace .

Comment: Pensei na mesma coisa @MarconcilioSouza, mas isto não é necessário. O jeito que está na pergunta está certo.

Comment: Vinicius, você referenciou o projeto `Game.Logic` neste projeto?

Comment: @jbueno, ele pode usar uma referencia de um a assembly e continuar usando o mesmo namespace? .... `namespace Game.Logic.AI` ...  `using Game.Logic.AI;`

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Isso eu já não sei. Estou falando sobre declarar o `using` depois do `namespace`.